# click fires twice on some item but not others

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a jQuery plugin in order to style my select inputs. So far it works well.

On the fiddle I marked the clickable area with a background color. When you click on any of these they should get a class if it doesn't have it already and remove it if does have the class already.

This only works on some items and not on other and I noticed it is because on some items the class is added and then removed directly after.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please. Not sure what the problem could be.

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <h1>Select with icons</h1>
    <select class="select-image" data-icons="true">
        <option value="option 1" data-image-class="o-1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option 2" data-image-class="o-2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option 3" data-image-class="o-3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option 4" data-image-class="o-4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option 5" data-image-class="o-5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="option 6" data-image-class="o-6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="option 7" data-image-class="o-7">Option 7</option>
        <option value="option 8" data-image-class="o-8">Option 8</option>
        <option value="option 9" data-image-class="o-9">Option 9</option>
        <option value="option 10" data-image-class="o-10">Option 10</option>
    </select>
</section>

<section>
    <h1>Select without icons</h1>
    <select class="select-no-image">
        <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option 3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option 4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option 5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="option 6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="option 7">Option 7</option>
        <option value="option 8" selected="selected">Option 8</option>
        <option value="option 9">Option 9</option>
        <option value="option 10">Option 10</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
; (function($, window, document, undefined) {
'use strict';

var hasIcon = false;
var activeClass = '';
var count = 1;

$.fn.extend({
    select: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            activeClass : 'cp-select-active'
        }

        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var o = options;

            function setupSelect(el) {
                var $this = $(el);
                var icons = $this.data('icons') ? hasIcon = true : hasIcon = false;

                if(!Modernizr.touch) {

                    $this.attr('data-id', 'select-' + count++);

                    if(hasIcon) {
                        var selected = $this.find(':selected');
                        var selectContainer = '<div class="cp-select"><span>'
                                            + '<i class="' + selected.data('image-class') 
                                            + '"></i>' + selected.text() 
                                            + '</span><ul class="cp-select-dropdown"></ul></div>';

                        $this.after(selectContainer);
                        $this.addClass('hide');

                        buildList($this, true);
                        referenceListToSelect($this, count - 1);
                    } else {
                        var selected = $this.find(':selected');
                        var selectContainer = '<div class="cp-select"><span>' 
                                            + selected.text() 
                                            + '</span><ul class="cp-select-dropdown"></ul></div>';

                        $this.after(selectContainer);
                        $this.addClass('hide');

                        buildList($this, false);
                        referenceListToSelect($this, count - 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            function buildList(el, bool) {
                var element = $(el);
                var select = element.nextUntil('ul.cp-select-dropdown');

                element.find('option').each(function() {
                    if(bool) {
                        var icon = '<i class="' + $(this).data('image-class') + '"></i>';
                    } else {
                        var icon = '';
                    }
                    var listItem = '<li class="cp-select-list" data-value="' 
                                + $(this).attr('value') + '"><a href="#">' + icon
                                + $(this).text() + '</a></li>';

                    select.find('ul.cp-select-dropdown').append(listItem);
                });
            }

            function referenceListToSelect(element, number) {
                var select = element.nextUntil('ul.cp-select-dropdown');
                select.find('li.cp-select-list').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('data-item-of', number);
                });
            }

            function openSelect() {
                $('.cp-select').on('click','span', function() {
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass(o.activeClass);
                });
            }

            function makeSelection() {
                $('li.cp-select-list a').on('click', function() {

                }); 
            }

            setupSelect(this);
            openSelect();
        });
    }
});

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/w0jggjpb/11/

**Updated fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/w0jggjpb/16/

Comment: The code is quite lengthy for what you seem to want, but the obvious problem would be adding event handlers repeatedly and never removing them. That would accumulate 1, then 2 then 3 events etc. Use delegated event handlers instead (attached to an ancestor element).

Comment: It is a lot, I know. I updated my fiddle following your advice (that is if I understood correctly). I don't think the problem is that the event is accumulating though because after load when you click on the first item, it doesn't work but when you click on the second item it works, so there was no other events before I clicked on the first item. Nothing to accumulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event is being bound inside a `.each()`  loop.

```
return this.each(function() { //...
```

That is why it's only the top `.cp-select` that fires twice, because when your loop runs 2 times, the first element gets bound twice to the click event.

To give you a simplified solution, delegate the click event through for example the body (this might not be best practice) or any other container you dont create dynamically.

```
$("body").on("click", ".cp-select span", function(){ //....
```

And do that a place you know you only do it once.